# Breaking constraints in tableHeaderView

Tags: ios8, autolayout, constraints

I have UILabel into UIView xib. my tableView contain that view in tableHeaderView. 
Label has next constraints:

[image]

And in runtime I get next warning in console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feaf3969800 H:|-(77)-[UILabel:0x7feaf3968e00'ThreeWithLngNameVeryLong ...']   (Names: '|':HeaderView:0x7feaf3968040 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feaf39698a0 H:[UILabel:0x7feaf3968e00'ThreeWithLngNameVeryLong ...']-(16)-|   (Names: '|':HeaderView:0x7feaf3968040 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feaf397b4d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[HeaderView:0x7feaf3968040(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7feaf39698a0 H:[UILabel:0x7feaf3968e00'ThreeWithLngNameVeryLong ...']-(16)-|   (Names: '|':HeaderView:0x7feaf3968040 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Maybe someone know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, you set the Trailing and the Leading base on the superview.
But you also have the width set too, I don't know what the HeaderView here is.
But the width of the Header maybe relate to the constraints of the label, so they are conflict.

Try remove the header width constraint to check if it's solved

Comment: Yes, they are conflicted. But question is why they conflict? 'Cause with iOS 8 we don't need to set width for labels. We have preferredWidth 'Automatic' and it's working as well in most cases.(in iOS 7 we need to set width value for this property).
But, for some reason, it's not working when we put UIView into tableHeaderView.